# How to disable a button on user change in Login form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a scenario where I have a login application like below

- When user is set to Faculty then Form 2 -> button1 should get disabled

  [image: faculty]
- When user is set to Admin then Form 2 -> button1 should get enabled

  [image: admin]

**How to achieve this using C# windows application ?**

Comment: Hi, are you having problems implementing a solution for these scenarios? Please post the relevant code so that we can help you. Also, is this a WinForms, UWP or WPF application?

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'Modifiers' property of the Form2 -> button1 to Public. Then add this code to the Click event of the login button:

```
    Form_2 frm=new Form_2();
    If(comboBoxUser.SelectedItem=="Faculty")
    {
            frm.button1.Enabled=false;
    }
    else
    {
            frm.button1.Enabled=true;
    }
```